# How do you search ldap in php by the true DN of the object?

Tags: php, ldap

The problem I am having is that the string `$named2` will work string `$named1` will not return any results...

Here is my example:

```
$root_dn = "DC=na,DC=company,DC=net";

$named1 = "CN=Murray\, James,OU=Users,OU=USA,DC=na,DC=company,DC=net";

$named2 = "CN=empNum12345,OU=Users,OU=USA,DC=na,DC=company,DC=net";


$named_arr = explode("OU=",$named1,15);
$named_arr[0] = rtrim($named_arr[0], ',');

$ldap_query = $named_arr[0]; //CN=Murray\, James

if($connect_id) {

    ldap_set_option($connect_id, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($connect_id, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = ldap_bind($connect_id, $LDAP_LGIN[$SERVER_ID], $LDAP_PASS[$SERVER_ID]);

    $sr=ldap_search($connect_id, $LDAP_ROOT_DN[$SERVER_ID], $ldap_query);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($connect_id, $sr);
    $count = $info["count"];
    $rs = ldap_flatresults($connect_id, $sr);

    echo $rs;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting bc004346!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that seems to break your search is the escaped comma in the CN of James Murray. It's passed over to the `ldap_seach` and that can't find anything with that search-string.

So one solution would be to strip the backslash before passing the string to `ldap_search` like this:

```
$ldap_query = str_replace('\\', '', $named_arr[0]);
```

The alternative (and in my eyes easier) solution would be to use the DN you already have and fetch the data for exactly that DN by replacing your `ldap_search` with this:

```
$sr = ldap_read($connect_id, $named1, "objectclass=*");
```

That should give you all attributes of James Murray.

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark the answer as your solution. ;)